# How to give administrative privileges when installing CMake

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, matplotlib-basemap

I am using the instructions from https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap to install Basemap on my macOS Monterey, Python3.9
I have installed all prerequisites but in step 3:
"Build the GEOS library. You may use the helper provided in utils, i.e.

```
export GEOS_DIR=<your desired location>
python -c "import utils; utils.GeosLibrary('3.5.1').build(installdir='${GEOS_DIR}')"
```

I get the following Error:

```
CMake Error at include/cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/include/geos.  Maybe need administrative
  privileges.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
```

I have tried to run sudo make install and running again with no success.
Is any way to work around privileges on CMake?

Comment: Not sure what the first snippet does, but usually `sudo cmake --install ...` should work, which should be the equivalent to `sudo make install` run from the build directory. One  thing worth checking would be, if the re is already a non-directory file named `/usr/include/geos`, since in that case creating a directory in that place would be impossible, admin privileges or not.

Comment: What is your value for `GEOS_DIR`? From your traceback I would assume it is `/usr`. If this is the case, you can try to set `GEOS_DIR` to a folder owned by your user.